# JS Regex returning -1 & 0

Tags: javascript, regex

I was tasked with the following:

1. take a string
2. print each of the vowels on a new line (in order) then...
3. print each of the consonants on a new line (in order)

The problem I found was with the regex. I originally used...

```js
/[aeiouAEIOU\s]/g
```

But this would return 0 with a vowel and -1 with a consonant (so everything happened in reverse).
I really struggled to understand why and couldn't for the life of me find the answer. In the end it was simple enough to just invert the string but I want to know why this is happening the way it is. Can anyone help?

```js
let i;
let vowels = /[^aeiouAEIOU\s]/g;
let array = [];
function vowelsAndConsonants(s) {
    for(i=0;i<s.length;i++){
        //if char is vowel then push to array
        if(s[i].search(vowels)){
           array.push(s[i]);         
        }
        
    }
    for(i=0;i<s.length;i++){
        //if char is cons then push to array
        if(!s[i].search(vowels)){
           array.push(s[i]);         
        }      
    }
    for(i=0;i<s.length;i++){
        console.log(array[i]);    
    }
}

vowelsAndConsonants("javascript");
```

Comment: you want the `.test` function, which returns true or false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if(vowels.test(s[i])){` which will return true or false if it matches, or
`if(s[i].search(vowels) !== -1){` and `if(s[i].search(vowels) === -1){`
is what you want if you want to fix your code.
-1 is not falsey so your if statement will not function correctly.  -1 is what search returns if it doesn't find a match.  It has to do this because `search()` returns the **index position of the match**, and the index could be anywhere from 0 to Infinity, so only negative numbers are available to indicate non-existent index:
[MDN search() reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search)

Below is a RegEx that matches vowel OR any letter OR other, effectively separating out vowel, consonant, everything else into 3 capture groups.  This makes it so you don't need to test character by character and separate them out manually.
Then iterates and pushes them into their respective arrays with a for-of loop.

```js
const consonants = [], vowels = [], other = [];

const str = ";bat cat set rat. let ut cut mut,";

for(const [,cons,vow,etc] of str.matchAll(/([aeiouAEIOU])|([a-zA-Z])|(.)/g))
  cons&&consonants.push(cons) || vow&&vowels.push(vow) || typeof etc === 'string'&&other.push(etc)

console.log(
consonants.join('') + '\n' + vowels.join('') + '\n' + other.join('')
)
```

Comment: Thanks! that was what I was getting wrong. I thought search() would return true or false. Thanks for explaining it :)

Answer (score 0):

You used:

```
/[^aeiouAEIOU\s]/g
```

Instead of:

```
/[aeiouAEIOU\s]/g
```

`^` means "not", so your REGEX `/[^aeiouAEIOU\s]/g` counts all the consonants.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of inbuilt functions available:

```js
let some_string = 'Mary had a little lamb';

let vowels = [...some_string.match(/[aeiouAEIOU\s]/g)];
let consonents = [...some_string.match(/[^aeiouAEIOU\s]/g)];

console.log(vowels);
console.log(consonents);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you don't understand correctly how your regular expression works. In the brackets you have only defined a set of characters you want to match `/[^aeiouAEIOU\s]/g` and further by using the caret `[^]`as first in your group, you say that you want it to match everything but the characters in the carets. Sadly you don't provide an example of input and expected output, so I am only guessing, but I thing you could do the following:

```
let s = "avndexleops";
let keep_vowels = s.replace(/[^aeiouAEIOU\s]/g, '');
console.log(keep_vowels);
let keep_consonants = s.replace(/[aeiouAEIOU\s]/g, '');
console.log(keep_consonants);
```

Please provide example of expected input and output.

Comment: for expected in / out, let's say:
"javascript"
"aaijvscrpt"

The full code that I provided is the one that works. But my expectation is that "/[aeiouAEIOU\s]/g" should return 1 / true if it's a vowel and 0 / false if it's anything else.

What actually happened though was that it would return -1 if it was a consonant and 0 if it was a vowel :/

Comment: `search()` has to return -1, because search returns an index, which could be any number from 0 to Infinity.  You are looking for the `test()` function